# Count Inventory of Product

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have table Bill Detail for store Product infor.

When i input product with price and input with repository and quantity.

And i get output product by get product id with repository and quantity

Now i need count inventory of product in repository.

Example:

Bii Detail Data:

```
Type    Product_ID Repository_id Qty
1       2          2             1
1       2          2             3
2       2          2             1
1       2          3             2
1       2          3             3
2       2          3             2
```

Note: Type: 1: Input, 2: output

Folow data: Total Inventory of product 2 in repository 2 has:

```
  Total Input - Total output = (1+3) - 1 = 3
```

I need sql for:
- List all repository has product: Example with product 2, has 2 repository 2, and 3
- Total Inventory of product with repository: Example, with product 2 and repository 3. Total Inventory is 3.

So how can i using SQL for query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL
You could use a sum and group by  and case when based on type

```
  select 
      Product_ID
    , Repository_id
    , sum(case when type = 1 then Qty 
               when typ2 = 2 then -Qty
          END) total
  from my_table 
  group by       
      Product_ID
    , Repository_id
```

Comment: how can i where with condition total > 0 ?

Comment: you can add  `having total>0` after the group by clause